# the number of ice cream cones sold can be shown by N(x)=(100logx)+21,

Tags: algebra-precalculus

question: the number of ice cream cones sold can be shown by N(x)=(100logx)+21, where x is the number of days since the beginning of july, the price of ice cream cones is shown by p(x)=0.05x^3 + 0.03x^2 where x is the amount of days since july 1st. what is the rate of change of revenue between July 5th&26th

I have yet to have done differentiation, this is just precalc but I dont know how to set this up to give me the equation for rate of change as in f(x2)-f(x1) divided by (x2)-(x1)

Comment: the revenue is equal to the price times quantity. So $f(x)=N(x)\cdot p(x)$. Now you can evaluate the change of $f(x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Your thought for rate of change is correct.  You need to plug into the equations to find the number of cones sold on the $5^{th}$ and the $26^{th}$ and the price they are sold at.  How do you get the revenue once you have the number of cones and the price per cone?